# How to simulate your chat bot is "writing" a response using the Facebook Messenger API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I've seen some chat bots released during the F8 conference that display the three point "writing" bubble before answering. Haven't found any documentation as to how to reproduce that behavior in my chat bot, is it a special payload or some kind of configuration or special message that must be sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is when you have Button Template and someone click on "button" for "postback" ([documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#guidelines) in section "button teplate").

Then during your parsing of message a sending answer, it is shown like "writing".

Comment: Is there a way to force this behavior? When I ask something to the bot, it calls some 3rd parties API... I'd like to simulate the "writing" also while it's waiting for the API response

Answer (score 1):

Right with the help of [THIS](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#sendtyping) method sendTyping

This is what the doc says

> Sends the user an indication that the bot is typing. For long running
>   operations this should be called every few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the sender actions fields in the api (documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/sender-actions)).

E.g.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "sender_action":"typing_on"
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Will start the 3 dots animation. This automatically stops after 20s or after the "typing_off" sender action.